# Would like to know if it's possible to retrieve adminId within Reverse Geocode v7?

Tags: here-api, reverse-geocoding

Recently we are considering several solutions to perform reverse geocoding to get administrative data from the geo lat, long.

Since v6.2 Reverse Geocode API actually provide the query param to allow retrieving admin area **Identifier** within the resolved response.

Is it possible to use V7 API to get those information as well?

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html